# how to make a while loop with two conditions

Tags: php

this is my first question here
I want to display uploaded files , each one with its description.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE id='$this->id' AND type='$this->type'
ORDER BY `pid` desc";

if ($query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo 'Successful';
}else{  
    echo 'error';
}

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0 ){  
    $dir = 'uploads/'.$this->id.'/videos';
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)) && $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) 
    {
        if($entry !== "Thumbs.db" && $entry !== "." && $entry !== "..") { 
            echo "<tr><td></td><td><a target='new' href='".$dir."/$entry'>$entry</a><br>"
            . "<video width='320' height='240' controls><source src='".$dir."/$entry' type='video/mp4'></video></td><td>".$row['vid_desc']."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
```

it just prints "Successful" and no files or decriptions returned although I have 2 entries

Update:

the while loop works properly but it doesn't read what inside the folder, I removed the if statement inside the while loop and changed the $dir to other directories and it doesn't read any thing except (.) and (..) which refers to parent directories, although these new directories have ,at least, two files inside each of them.

Comment: How are you not getting a syntax error with this? `if($entry !== "Thumbs.db" && $entry !== "." && $entry !== {`

Comment: Sorry it's a typo while editing the code here. I just fixed it.

Comment: Check how many times the while loop executes by echoing from within it, and check what the variables are, to find whatever is going wrong. This code looks fine to me, which means something else is going wrong. Maybe the folder is wrong? Not sure.

Comment: I removed the if statement and echoed $entry.'<br>'; 
and it just echoes :
.
..
although I have 2 files inside this folder.

then I changed the direction to other folders and the same thing happens, it ignores any files inside the folder and just echoes 3 dots.

Comment: what I'm sure about now is that the while loop works properly and the two conditions get excuted but the problem now is that it doesn't read what inside the folders properly..
thank you for answering. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you paste what you get when you echo `$sql`?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `portfolio` WHERE id='2' AND type='video' ORDER BY `pid` desc

Comment: now it prints both of them but it doesn't put each file with its description